# How to do a curl post request and only get status code in response?

Tags: curl, post

```
$response="$(curl -s -w '%{http_code}' -X POST --cert /Users/../cert --key /Users/../key -H content-type:application/json -d@./file https://someurl)"

$echo $response

{}201
```

I am currently getting {}201 in my response. However I only want 201 in my response, not {}.

How should i modify the curl?

Answer (score 0):

```
$echo $response | cut -d"}" -f 2
```

The output of the response is piped to the command `cut`.

With `cut`, we'll cut off anything which comes before the `}` string.

In this way, the output will be e.g.:

`201`

Comment: oh sorry, ok please add some text with your answer.. :)